# How to configure "hibernate-mapping" to "field"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to specify via standard JPA `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(String,Map<String,String>)` to hibernate to use "hibernate-mapping" to "field" rather than "property".

How can I do this, the clean way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA determines which mapping type to use based on where you put your `@Id` annotation.  So if you put your `@Id` annotation on a field then the mapping will be field-based.

UPDATE:

In JPA 2.0 You can also use the `@Access` annotation.  You can apply it to the class to specify the access type for the entire entity and you can apply it to individual fields/methods to override the default for a single field/property.